# How to Pass finish() from Activity class as a function parameter (So the code can be reused in Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin, arguments, parameter-passing

I have to use this peice of code twice in two different places in two different activites. No good programmer would willingly want to use same code in multiple places without reusing it.

```
//when back key is pressed
        override fun onBackPressed() {
            dialog.setContentView(twoBtnDialog.root)
            twoBtnDialog.title.text = getString(R.string.warning)
            twoBtnDialog.msgDialog.text = getString(R.string.backPressWarning)
            twoBtnDialog.ok.text = getString(R.string.exit)
            twoBtnDialog.cancel.text = getString(R.string.cancel)
            twoBtnDialog.ok.setOnClickListener {
                //do nav back
                finish()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            twoBtnDialog.cancel.setOnClickListener {
                dialog.dismiss()    //just do nothing
            }
            dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            dialog.show()
        }
```

I can move it to one place, but the problem is I have to pass in the **finish()** function from **Activity Class** to close the calling activity.

My simple question is how can I resue it ? Or How can I pass this function (**finish()**) to a different class (which is in some other file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a function type parameter in your method.

```
fun doBackPress(finish: () -> Unit) {
    // you need to invoke the finish method when necessary
    finish.invoke()
}
```

Then you need to call the method and have to pass the `finish()` method from any other activity or fragment method like bellow.

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    doBackPress { finish() }
}
```

Comment: Seems like it will work, but there is one problem, I have to pass in twoBtnDialog variable also and I can't find a way to do this when using this method.

Comment: You can invoke the method on the click listener of the `twoBtnDialog` buttons. If you want to pass it to dialog then you need a setter or constructor to pass the method as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You could make an interface and extension function, which I think is less messy than trying to pass everything you need as parameters to a function, because it communicates intent better and makes it harder to do something wrong.

```
interface MyDialogOwner {
    val dialog: Dialog
    val twoBtnDialog: MyDialogBinding

    fun Activity.handleBackPress() {
        //the exact same content you have in your function now.
    }
}

// In Activity:
override fun onBackPressed() = handleBackPress()
```

Your Activities should implement the interface, using your existing properties for `dialog` and `twoBtnDialog` (just add `override` in front of their declarations).

I'm assuming `twoBtnDialog` is a view binding.

Comment: I made it to work using Arif's answer. But your answer and more easy and clear, so let me try.